# C# access JSON content by ID

Tags: c#, json

So I need to parse a JSON string from my C# project.
I get my JSON as a response from a method call and the json looks like this:

```
{
    "10": {
        "entity_id": "10",
        "attribute_set_id": "4",
        "type_id": "simple",
        "sku": "convertor-touchscreen",
        "name": "Convertor touchscreen",
        "meta_title": null,
        "meta_description": null,
        "url_key": "convertor-touchscreen",
        "custom_design": null,
        "page_layout": null,
        "options_container": "container1",
        "country_of_manufacture": null,
        "msrp_enabled": "2",
        "msrp_display_actual_price_type": "4",
        "gift_message_available": null,
        "creareseo_discontinued": null,
        "creareseo_discontinued_product": null,
        "description": "Convertor touchscreen",
        "short_description": "Convertor touchscreen",
        "meta_keyword": null,
        "custom_layout_update": null,
        "price": "421.0000",
        "special_price": "380.0000",
        "weight": "0.1500",
        "msrp": null,
        "special_from_date": "2015-11-24 00:00:00",
        "special_to_date": "2015-11-26 00:00:00",
        "news_from_date": null,
        "news_to_date": null,
        "custom_design_from": null,
        "custom_design_to": null,
        "status": "1",
        "visibility": "4",
        "tax_class_id": "2",
        "featured": "1"
    }
}
```

So I need to access members like "entity_id","name" and so on...
so I tried

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
...
// output is the above JSON string
var jo = JObject.Parse(output);
var id = jo[0]["entity_id"].ToString();
```

But obviously it's not a good way to do it.
Also, I do not have control over the first part

```
{
    "10": {
```

So I cannot do

```
var id = jo["10"]["entity_id"].ToString();
```

because I do not know what the value "10" will be in my next JSON string.
So how can I get the element value by an Id or something?

Comment: It's not clear what you *do* know. Will there only ever be a single entity in the JSON? What do you think is "not a good way" about what you've got?

Answer (score 3):

If you don't know the value of `10` in advance it's obvious that you cannot access its contents using this key (in your example that would be the key to access the other properties). If this object will always have 1 top level property then your code is just fine:

```
var jo = JObject.Parse(output);
var id = jo[0]["entity_id"].ToString();
```

with some added defensive checks that the `jo` array has at least one property before trying to access it.

On the other hand if the *key* is inside some property of the entity that you know about it, then feel free to loop over all the top level properties of the `jo` variable inspecting the sub-properties for the values of the key you know about until you find the desired record.

Comment: I think you are missing the point. I cannot access the property because I do not know the value of "10". So I would have to go by ID, but I get an error if I try to do that. So the code you wrote above is the same I placed in my question as an example of NON-working code: error : `Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.`

Comment: I came to a working solution, so I will change a bit the question: how can I access the JSON if there are multiple top 1 level elements and I do not know them?

Comment: If there are multiple top level elements and you don't know them and you don't know what you want to access then what exactly do you expect to be able to achieve? You can of course loop through all the top level elements but if you don't know what you are looking for chances for finding it are close to zero.

Answer (score 0):

So I came to a conclussion on my own:
If the JSON contains only one top 1 level element (the "10" in my case) then I can access the properties inside this element just like:

```
var descr = output.description;
var entid = output.entity_id;
... and so on
```

I still don't know how to access a JSON that contains multiple top level 1 elements. But I will make that a different question.